# Возможно ли законектить Edge, Сhrome или Firefox через webRTC?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, webrtc

Кто-то пробовал законектить Edge, Chrome или Firefox через WebRTC. У меня нечего не получается. Может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Что не получается, что пробовали делать? Опишите подробнее Ваши действия и внесите правку в вопрос.

Comment: Связанная статья: https://habrahabr.ru/company/Voximplant/blog/334498/